# How to modify table row borders (antd)?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am working on displaying a report using a tree table component from ant design.

I would like to make the bottom border of the collapsed parent or of the last expanded child in order to split the report into it's sections.

**Current Situation Vs. Desired Effect**
[image]

Ideally I need a way to set the css class name through an attribute in the table data source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All border attributes will not work at the  level. They must be on the  level. So, just giving a class name that modifies the border to a row won't work.

A workaround would be to set a class name using the Antd "rowClassName" prop (this can be set to a function that dynamically returns the class names).

Then, assign the following classes:

```
.highlight-bottom-border > td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black !important
}

.highlight-top-border > td {
  border-top: solid 2px black !important;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #6d9eff !important
}
```

By doing so, the  level is modified resulting in a more defined border.

Answer (score 1):

you can customize the className in JSX tags and add css property
You can find the target className in the inspection

> .customizeClassName {   :global {
> .targetAntdClassName {
> border: none
> }   } }